# Extra space appearing out of nowhere (Please Look)

Tags: c++

Here is my code, please compile and help me figure out where that extra space before the first line of the unsorted numbers comes from. I've spent at least 6 hours trying to figure it out and I can't. Sorry for wasting your time if it's an easy answer. I appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you!

http://cpp.sh/7tg5q

Comment: I entered 2,2,3 and it looks fine. You will need to explain what you *expect*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), with special attention to ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, you should post your code, not a link to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in lines 36 and 39.

In this case, std::setw and std::setprecision only operate on the next number.  In other words

```
std::cout << std::setw(3) << 10 << std::endl;
std::cout << 10;
```

Will output

```
 10
10
```

There isn't an extra space in front of the first.  Rather, the second is lacking a space.

Redefine your print function:

```
void printArray( double array[], int numberOfValues, int numberPerLine, int spaces, int digits );
```

Call it like this:

```
printArray( array, numberOfValues, numberPerLine, spaces, digits );
```

And add the setw and setprecision lines to the appropriate cout statements:

```
for (i = 1; i <= numberOfValues; i++) {
    if ( i % numberPerLine == 0 ) {
        cout << setw(spaces) << setprecision(digits) << array[i-1] << endl;
    } else {
        cout << setw(spaces) << setprecision(digits) << array[i-1] << "\t";
    }
}
```

Everything will be spaced right.  Note that this still doesn't fix the lack of std::fixed.  You won't be showing the number of digits requested by the second input.